# How do I refix everything in the xml for different phone sizes?

Tags: android, xml, screen, resolution

I'm trying to remake my views and layouts in xml for different phone screen sizes in Android Studio.

Is there an easy way to resize the image views and other widgets bigger or smaller? For example, make this image views dimensions 150% size now, as in just to scale the dp values up because right now I'm going back in and retyping new dp values and dragging everything again and there's so many different views and screen sizes it's taking me forever.

Also when I created the different layouts small, normal, large and xlarge, it uses the normal xml for phone sizes that displays it just a bit off. Like it uses the normal xml that would fit the 5.5inch Pixel XL but not for the 5 inch nexus 5. How do I create a new xml one for the 5inch screen. When I go to create other do I have to specify the screen height and screen width or do I just specify the width or height?

I built my whole app xml's in 5.5 screen size ana I really didn't plan ahead with the different screen sizes so its mostly all hardcoded in dp values and now it's a gigantic mess to do every screen size.

Answer (score 0):

This is my ImageView which gets perfect on all size screen. You will just change all your images with this type, and you will never face this issue again. You will just change at one place whenever you want change size.

```
<ImageView
            android:layout_width="@dimen/profile_pic_size_big"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/profile_pic_size_big"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_folder"
            />
```

**I always use dimens for this issue. When i need to change size of anything like text or image, i just need to change in my dimen.xml and every where it is changed.**

You will have to give some time to use some default sizes for your app layouts.

- Every app have some fixed size for images everywhere like icons, banners. So you will define that dimens in dimens.xml.

**But thing is how to make supportive layout.**

There can be different ways, i am telling best which i found. Long method is to make layouts or dimens for every type of screen like (xdpi or xxdpi or xxxdpi). But this is very time consuming task.

- [sdp](https://github.com/intuit/sdp) is a excellent library which i got after very hard time in some projects.
- You just have regular dimens.xml in `res>values`. and you will use **sdp** instead of **dp**.

[image: what you get]

**Here is mine, you can use this as well**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources>
    <dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">16dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="activity_vertical_margin">16dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="tvVerySmall">@dimen/_10ssp</dimen>
    <dimen name="tvSmall">@dimen/_12ssp</dimen>
    <dimen name="tvNormal">@dimen/_14ssp</dimen>
    <dimen name="tvLarge">@dimen/_16ssp</dimen>
    <dimen name="tvtVeryLarge">@dimen/_18ssp</dimen>
    <dimen name="drawablePadding">5dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="profile_pic_size_big">110dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="profile_pic_size_medium">50dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="space_large">@dimen/_16sdp</dimen>
    <dimen name="space_small">@dimen/_8sdp</dimen>
    <dimen name="circleHeightWidth">@dimen/_70sdp</dimen>
    <dimen name="circleHeightWidthSmall">45dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="toolbar_icon_padding">17dp</dimen>
    <!--default card view margin must be greater than elevation-->
    <dimen name="cardViewDefaultMargin">3dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="corner_radius_default">2dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="elevation_default">2dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="buttonPaddingVertical">@dimen/_10sdp</dimen>
    <dimen name="buttonPaddingHorizontal">@dimen/_20sdp</dimen>

    <dimen name="buttonSmallPaddingVertical">@dimen/_6sdp</dimen>
    <dimen name="buttonSmallPaddingHorizontal">@dimen/_15sdp</dimen>

</resources>
```